# Simple DataBase Manager for C#

Tags: c#, database

I'm writing a simple program in C# which stores some data and then use simple queries to generate reports, ... .

the data are about **a million** records.

what's an efficient way to do this? should I use MsSql, MySql, ..., or there is a easier way to manage and use this amount of data?

**UPDATE:** actually by *efficient* I meant *simple*. I want my program to standalone if possible. using simple files for storing data, etc. but I don't want to create everything from scratch.

tnx

Comment: The database platform is irrelevant. Make sure your database schema is designed well so that querying your data is efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably either MS SQL Server or MySQL would be just fine. Both systems are used for commercial products and have a robust set of tools for something like that.

Look into SQL Express, which is a lite version of SQL Server. And it's free. [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)

There is also [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) which you can actually *embed* into your application (no need for a server or installation).

Comment: yeah, you are quite right. but I prefer not to use any 3rd party database Server so my program can works simply without any _massive_ install.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) if you want your program to be standalone and simple. Those databases are quite fast, also. From my experiences, SQLite is a word class standalone/embeddable database. I'd prefer it over SQLServer Compact edition and other candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Richard is correct, any of the main stream database engines will be sufficient.  Since you're dealing with a lot of data, you'll want to consider adjusting your schema as needed for reporting, or create aggregate roll-up tables to make reports run faster.  There's no reason to query old data over and over again when doing aggregate operations.  Lastly, make sure you create the appropriate indexes on the columns you're filtering and ordering by.

Good Luck!

Comment: That's a great "short list" of things to be mindful of when creating his db.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using SQL Server Compact. It uses the microsoft stack so should be easy to use with C#. Also, since it is an embedded database it doesnt need a server to run on - it will run stand-alone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275.aspx